# Brightness settings not working, stuck on Zero brightness

Tags: brightness

I just recently installed Ubuntu on my computer, so a I am a little new at using this OS.

It seems to work fine and run smoothly other than my brightness settings are not working, beyond using the key board FN keys, the actual Brightness and Lock settings have no effect on the brightness.

The brightness seems to almost be turned off, its very hard to see anything and I have no idea what to do, any help would be very appreciated.

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 on an Acer Aspire 5336 and my System Details are:

- Intel Celeron(R) CPU 900 @ 2.20 GHZ,
- Graphics Card; Intel GM Express Chipset
- 64 bit with 250 GB hard drive.

Comment: What **Ubuntu** version? eg. 12.04, 13.04

Answer (score 0):

sudo software-properties-gtk

Click on the Additional Drivers tab in the Software Sources menu

Install your device drivers

Answer (score 0):

With 'setpci' you should be able to adjust the brightness. In order to be able to apply this, you need to boot into Recovery first, with boot option nomodeset.
Explanation:
https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/display#TOC-Brightness-of-the-display-is-wrong-and-not-adjustable
(item 2.5, right column)

It worked for me, on my Acer 5336.... :-)